# Logical Operators in Java

Tags: java, logical-operators

How does Java compile or evaluate the following codes with the logical operators? 
Which pair is executed first?

```
else if ((((assign/50)>=0.8) && (((exam/100)<=0.35) || ((exam/100)>=0.4))) ||
                (((exam/100)>=0.8) && (((assign/50)<=0.35) || ((assign/50)>=0.4)))) {
            System.out.println("Pushed Up");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how does Java compiler evaluate the following.."?

Comment: Here is an operator precedence table: http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html

Comment: How does Java execute the code? Which one has highest priority? && or || ? and how does Java execute it ?

Comment: The table is worth a look, but just know that Java also short-circuits, so, if the necessary conditions are met before all options are checked, Java won't even try the other options, opting instead to enter the body of whatever statement.

Comment: For example, (assign/50)>=0.8) && (((exam/100)<=0.35) --> this statement is not true. 

Does Java consider this pair of statement (((exam/100)<=0.35) || ((exam/100)>=0.4) ?

Answer (score 2):

`&&` has priority over `||`. Rewritten with only necessary parens:

```
    assign / 50 >= 0.8 && (exam / 100 <= 0.35 || exam / 100 >= 0.4)
 || exam / 100 >= 0.8 && (assign / 50 <= 0.35 || assign / 50 >= 0.4)
```

In Java (like in many other languages), `&&` and `||` are [short-circuit operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Put simple:

```
1.  evaluate "assign / 50 >= 0.8"
2.  if true
3.      evalute "exam / 100 <= 0.35"
4.      if true
5.          return true
6.      else
7.          evaluate "exam / 100 >= 0.4"
8.          if true
9.              return true
10.         else
11.             goto 13.
12. else
13.     evaluate "exam / 100 >= 0.8"
14.     if true
15.         evaluate "assign / 50 <= 0.35"
16.         if true
17.             return true
18.         else
19.             evaluate "assign / 50 >= 0.4"
20.             if true
21.                 return true
22.             else
23.                 return false
24.     else
25.         return false
```

This may be quite useful. For example, an NPE will never be thrown in the following snippet:

```
if (myString != null && !myString.isEmpty()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Does the two && are executed first, then the || are executed in the block of statement ?

Comment: @user3545953 It is executed in the order I provided. What have you not understood?

Comment: The || in the statement.. How does Java consider it ?

Comment: @user3545953 In `b1 || b2 && b3`, `b1` (and not `b1 || b2`) will be evaluated first because `&&` has priority over `||`. If `true`, neither `b2` nor `b3` will be evaluated because of the short-circuit nature of those operators.